# How to read excel file with a grouped data

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a `.xlsx` file that looks like this:

[image]

I want to transform it into this one:

[image]

---

I'm not sure how to do it using python, because pandas cannot properly read the original file.

Comment: try reading it as a multiindex; you have three rows that are headers, so hopefully this should work: pd.read_csv('filename.csv', header=[0,1,2], index_col=[0]). header=[0,1,2] should read the first three rows as a header, and your dataframe should be a multiindex. Have a look at the pandas read_csv documentation for more info.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html

Comment: @sammywemmy it did work, thanks. I managed to melt it, though instead of `raw_value` and `percentage` I got a column for a type of the variable and another column for its value. Thanks for your suggestion!